# How do I install Android Studio 3.5 Canary 12?

Tags: android-studio

I need to install it, and downloaded the file, but it is in ZIP format. Inside the archive there is no `install` file, only `uninstall. How do I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't install the canary builds. They are meant to work alongside the stable versions which are installed.

For Windows, extract to some place like `C:\Programs\AndroidStudioCanary` and inside the `bin` there will be an executable file for 64bit version(and also for 32bit). Create a shortcut to the file and you are done.

For Linux, extract to some place like `/home/user/AndroidStudioCanary` and inside the `bin` there will be a bash script file `studio.sh`. After first launch close all projects via `File`->`Close projects` but do not close the IDE. Now in the main UI, click the settings cog and add desktop entry to create application shortcut.
[image: creating shortcut]

Launch the shortcut from applications now.

---

EDIT:

Canary and stable versions can run along side each other and their settings can be changed independently. For Windows and linux the folder named `.AndroidStudio3.6` will contain config for stable version and `.AndroidStudioCanary4.0` or similarly named folder will contain config for the canary version. These folders are inside user directory and are hidden. I don't have a mac but assume something similar.

Comment: Should we import stable Android Studio's settings to canary's Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

For canary builds, there are no traditional executable files that you use to "install" the IDE.

You can go into the `bin` folder, then run the `studio.exe` or `studio64.exe` file (depending on your platform) to run Android Studio